# How do I find the time difference between two events using the Google calender api python

Tags: python, google-api, google-api-python-client

I'm trying to create a program which checks my Google calender when I have been in work and whether it was overtime or normal rate and then calculate the amount I should be paid for that month. I have read over the Google API reference but I have had no luck. Here is my Pseudo code:

```
Get events for month
Write events to file split each value with comma
Check each event for keyword work else remove from file
For each line check amount of hours worked and append to end of line
If day = Sunday or event name = work (Overtime BH) append value to BankHolidayHours Variable
If day = Thursday or Saturday append value to ContractedHours variable
    Else write to OvertimeHours variable 
BankHolidayTotal = BankHolidayHours * BHRate
ContractedHoursTotal = ContractedHours * CHRate
OvertimeHoursTotal = OvertimeHours * OHRate
Print OvetimeHoursTotal & ContractedHoursTotal & BankHolidayTotal to screen
```

Any help will be much appreciated thanks.

Comment: Suggest showing us what one of your events "looks like" from the API. Also provide Python pseudocode, and point out where in the code it's not working as "I have had no luck" is just asking for this question to be shut down.

Answer (score 0):

Calculating the difference between two dates in Python can be done with [Timedelta](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#timedelta-objects)

Of course this has nothing to do with Google API. Maybe you should have asked a more specific question.